# Select box change default option to change other

Tags: php, jquery

I have a multiple select dropdown id will come dynamic while selecting first how i make another all select select box value should be change **please select**

```
<Select id="colorselector-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>">
 <option value="">Select</option>
 <option value="red">Red</option>
 <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
 <option value="blue">Blue</option>
```

```
<div id="red-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>" class="colors" style="display:none"> red... </div>
<div id="yellow-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>" class="colors" style="display:none"> yellow.. </div>
<div id="blue-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>" class="colors" style="display:none"> blue.. </div>
```

**script**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function($) {
$('#colorselector-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>').change(function(){
$('#dt2-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>').val("");
$('#dt1-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>').val("");
$('.colors').hide();
 $('#' + $(this).val() + '-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>').show();
 });

$('.chkbx-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>').click(function(){
var text = "";
$('.chkbx-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>:checked').each(function(){
text += $(this).val()+',';
});
text = text.substring(0,text.length-1);

$('#textbx-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>').val(text);
});
$(".individual-product-subescribe-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>").live("change", function() {
 $("#individual-product-subescribe-text-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
});
$('#individual-product-subescribe-text-<?php echo $_product->getId()?> option[value=Frank]').attr('selected','selected').change();
});
```

Comment: your question is not understandable kindly brief it in detail and if possible show image

Comment: What you want please describe properly.

Comment: @PavanBaddi  https://i.stack.imgur.com/35w92.png can you please check the image

Comment: @ImBS https://i.stack.imgur.com/35w92.png please check this image

Comment: @my Test ok i got it let me come up will similar example. and is it related to e-commerce site

Comment: Ya it's magento only

Comment: @my Test  then is it ok if give you jquery script because i don't know Magento

Comment: @my Test  here is my answere in jquery click on this [link](https://ibb.co/dotU5v). here when user click on first select tag then the second select tag gets activated when user clicks on second select tag the last two tag change to subscribe. tell me

Comment: How i access this url and code

Comment: If i select 1st select drop down then user goes to some other select box rest all select box valus show please select

Comment: @PavanBaddi You got any solution I am waiting for your reply

Answer (score 0):

@my Test here is my answere. The output is show in the image below click on the link.

[image: output 1]

[image: output 2]

HTML code and jquery script

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<section class="container" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <select class="select_1 form-control" id="select_1" data-id="<?php echo $id=1;?>">
                <option value="select">Select Color</option>
                <option value="red">Red</option>
                <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <select class="select_2 form-control" id="select_2" data-id="<?php echo $id=1;?>" disabled>
                <option value="select">Please  Select Week</option>
                <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
                <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
                <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
                <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
                <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <select class="select_3 form-control" id="select_3" data-id="<?php echo $id=1;?>" disabled>
                <option value="select">Please Select</option>
                <option value="Net banking">Net banking</option>
                <option value="Debit Cart">Debit Cart</option>
                <option value="Credit Cart">Credit Cart</option>
                <option value="Subscribe">Subscribe</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <select class="select_4 form-control" id="select_4" data-id="<?php echo $id=1;?>" disabled>
                <option value="select">Please Select</option>
                <option value="Cash On Delivery">Cash On Delivery</option>
                <option value="Gift Pack">Gift Pack</option>
                <option value="Subscribe">Subscribe</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".select_1").change(function(){
        var select_1_selected = $(".select_1").val();

        if(select_1_selected != 'select'){
            $(".select_2").prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else
        {
            $(".select_2").prop("disabled", true);
            $(".select_3").prop("disabled", true);
            $(".select_4").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });

    $(".select_2").change(function(){
        var select_1_selected = $(".select_2").val();

        if(select_1_selected != 'select'){
            $(".select_2").prop("disabled", false);
            $(".select_3").prop("disabled", false);
            $(".select_4").prop("disabled", false);

            $(".select_3, .select_4").html("<option>Subscribe</option>");
        }
        else
        {
            $(".select_3").prop("disabled", true);
            $(".select_4").prop("disabled", true);

            $(".select_3, .select_4").html("<option value='select'>Select</option>");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Feel free to ask question...

Comment: My id will be dynamic Select box id

Comment: What i mean is you are adding custom class name to select box like this select_2 but mine is different Based on product id Select box id will be changed

Comment: @my Test then here is what you can do ` ID="<?php echo $productid;?> `

Comment: Sorry i am not getting